# Console closing with only threads?

Tags: c#, multithreading, mutex

I ran into an issue where the application closes even though threads are running in the background when a while( true ) loop is not running on it's own(without a thread) in the main method.

Pseudo example:

```
public static void Method1() {
    while( true ) {}
}
public static void Method2() {
    while( true ) {}
}
public static void main() {
    Thread myThread1 = new Thread( () => Method1() );
    Thread myThread2 = new Thread( () => Method2() );
    myThread1.Start();
    myThread2.Start();
}
```

Now when that program runs, it stops execution after starting the threads, even though the threads are running infinite while loops. How do I void this? I know I can add an infinite loop in the main method, but that seems odd.

Someone recommended I use a mutex or semaphone, however I don't now where to start with those or how to apply them to my application.

Comment: strange, it does not exit for me.

Comment: Or you can use the TPL and perform a [WaitAll()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd270695%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) on the tasks you spawn.

Comment: Did you set `IsBackground = true` for thread?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think all you should need is to set the threads' IsBackground property to false:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.isbackground%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: From your link:
Background threads are identical to foreground threads, except that background threads do not prevent a process from terminating. Once all foreground threads belonging to a process have terminated, the common language runtime ends the process. Any remaining background threads are stopped and do not complete.

Comment: imho, It makes great sense to it in answer

Answer (score 1):

When the main thread exits, the app exits. That's normal.

You can just use [`Thread.Join`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/95hbf2ta.aspx) to wait for them both to terminate.

```
myThread1.Start();
myThread2.Start();
myThread1.Join(); 
myThread2.Join();
```

*Edit:* actually, [@adv12's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23462825/369) is better: set the threads to be foreground threads so that the app won't terminate until they finish.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use a mutex, see the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.mutex.aspx)

In the class

```
private static Mutex mut = new Mutex();
```

And in your methods use

```
mut.WaitOne();
mut.ReleaseMutex();
```

The main will exit but the threads will run until the mutex is released